# Use grep / sed for filename search & replace?

Tags: command-line, sed, grep, replace

I have a bunch of image files that were incorrectly named 'something@x2.png' and they need to be 'something@2x.png'. They're spread across multiple directories like so:

```
/images
    something@x2.png
    /icons
        icon@x2.png
    /backgrounds
        background@x2.png
```

How can I use grep + sed to find/replace as needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby(1.9+)

```
$ ruby -e 'Dir["**/*@x2.png"].each{|x| File.rename( x, x.sub(/@x2/,"@2x") ) }'
```

Answer (score 0):

#### With `bash 2.x/3.x`

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' file; do
  echo mv "$file" "${file/@x2/@2x}"
done < <(find images/ -type f -name "something*@x2*.png" -print0)
```

---

#### With `bash 4.x`

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s globstar

for file in images/**; do
  [[ "$file" == something*@x2*.png ]] && echo mv "$file" "${file/@x2/@2x}"
done
```

---

***Note:***
In each case I left in an `echo` so you can do a dry-run, remove the `echo` if the output is sufficient

Answer (score 0):

Look at qmv and rename

```
find -iname '*.png' -print0 | xargs -0 qmv -d
```

will launch your default editor and allow you to interactively edit the names

```
rename s/@x2/@2x/ *.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Slashes look linuxy/unixoid to me. Do you have find and rename?

```
find -name "*@x2*" -execdir rename 's/@x2/@2x/' {} +
```

rename is worth installing, comes in some perl-package.

Comment: I have find, but where can I get rename?

Comment: In the manpage, perl v5.10.1 is mentioned. apt-cache search says: `gprename - Complete batch renamer for Linux`